# @EnableTask annotation does not support DB2 on Mainframe on DB2ZOS

Tags: spring-cloud-task

We had a problem statement to convert a Mainframe DB2 long running job to convert to Spring Cloud Task.
It was working fine as a Spring Boot Ap, but when we tried to convert it to Spring cloud task as mentioned in 
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/
We got an exception saying DB2ZOS not found.
Please help.
Note:When we changed to MongoDB for a POC,it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this. I have created an issue to track this here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/issues/303

Comment: how much time it usually takes and when will the new JAR gets available.Sorry I am not making you hurry on this but just that we are planning for a production release so need plan accordingly or look for some alternate solutions.

Comment: It varies, fastest way to get this in is to create a pull request with the required changes. You an comment on the GitHub issue.